# Connecting to VPN Gate using Openvpn

Tags: openvpn, 18.10

I tried to connect to one of the open VPN server in https://www.vpngate.net/ using openvpn as a client. So what I did:

- download one of the ovpn files from one of the servers
- execute:

  sudo openvpn vpngateconfig.ovpn
- it last massage spouted:

  Initialization Sequence Completed

However, when I tried to ping any address across the web, it said

```
Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I tried to use different servers, but none of them worked. How to troubleshoot this? BTW, I'm using Ubuntu 18.10

regards

Edit:

```
~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=22.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=120 time=21.4 ms

~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53

~$ ps auxc | grep -i dns
etherea+  5292  0.0  0.0 340736  2988 ?        Sl   15:11   0:03 gvfsd-dnssd
~$ ps auxc | grep -i resolv
systemd+   735  0.0  0.0  55932  4000 ?        Ss   14:43   0:04 systemd-resolve
```

This happened when either VPN was up or down.

Comment: Does `ping 8.8.8.8` work when the VPN is up? Edit your question and show me the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and `ps auxc | grep -i resolv`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: ps: show me the `cat /etc/resolv.conf` when the VPN is up.

Comment: @heynnema I just added additional output that you requested

Comment: vpngate doesn't appear to support linux, and their .ovpn files are not updating your /etc/resolv.conf file, hence your dns requests are failing. Contact vpngate and ask them for the ddns name of their dns server for the particular vpn server that you're connecting to, and that can be edited into /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/ files so that /etc/resolv.conf will get properly updated.

Comment: they list ddns hosts name for all the server there. My /etc/resolvconf/ doesn't have resolv.conf.d directory. Should I create one and its file? What is the name of the file?

Comment: The ddns hosts name shown at vpngate are for the servers, probably not their DNS servers. You'll need to contact them to confirm. Do you have `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`?

Comment: yes, resolved.conf exists in my system

Comment: contact vpngate to get the ddns name for the DNS servers for your particular VPN server.

Comment: Just tried: I downloaded the openvpn file with ddns hostname and imported using network manager gui. All I had to set was the port number in the GUI. The connection was working after that.

Comment: @kukulo which network manager gui are you using?

Comment: Go to network settings, VPN, add new connection, open saved configuration. You should have installed network-manager-openvpn-gnome and network-manager-openvpn packages.

Comment: sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-openvpn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a nice GUI client that does all the work, from listing available VPNgate servers, to connect to one of the:

[Gvpngate](https://gwiz65.github.io/gvpngate/downloads.html)

Comment: this is gold, good find